# Html button styles are missing

Tags: html, asp.net

I created one html button and made it invisible like this:

```
<input id="btn" type="button" runat="server" value="Click" style="display:none; FONT-WEIGHT: 900; Z-INDEX: 105; WIDTH: 130px;" />.
```

I then made it visible at runtime like this:

```
btn.Attributes.CssStyle.Value = "display:normal"
```

But if I do it like this, the button control is missing whatever styles I added previously and it appears as a normal button.

Comment: made it invisible like how?

Comment: There isn't any option called 'display:normal'.. Please refer the below link for display options http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Comment: @MazeRunner OP is demonstrating on that bit of code.

Comment: HTML cannot be natively seen unless it's in a code block. Additionally, code blocks help people separate your question from your code. You can learn more about this on the [markdown page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 0):

You lose all existing inline CSS attributes when you set `CssStyle.Value`. Instead, you should set the display attribute specifically, like so:

```
btn.Attributes.CssStyle["display"] = "inline";
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
display: none;  //Do not use this
```

Use:

`visibility: hidden`

To make the button visible again, use:

```
btn.Attributes.CssStyle.Value = "visibility: visible"
```